# Unable to login via Devise after `devise_parameter_sanitizer` set in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

Previously, I've discussed an [issue here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2643) that enables login via username my app with rails 4. In 'Strong Parameters' part of [README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/README.md) of Devise, "the lazy way™" says additional parameters like "username" could be added with `configure_permitted_parameters` under `ApplicationController`. Then I copy-pasted code below the example into my app respectively, but it worked only `:sign_up` phase. So, I add other phases like this:

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :username
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) << :username
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :username
  end
```

But it didn't worked for any phase, so I removed all lines, even deleted the function, but nothing turns it back. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Devise version?
Try:

```
  protected
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:email, :password, :remember_me) }
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username,  :email, :password) }
  end
```